# ImageMagick Reflection

Tags: graphics, image, image-manipulation, imagemagick

Brief:

```
convert ( -size 585x128 gradient: )  NewImage.png
```

How do I change the above ImageMagick command so it takes the width and height from an existing image? I need it to remain a one line command.

---

Details:

I'm trying to programatically create an image reflection using ImageMagick. The effect I am looking for is similar to what you would see when looking at an object on the edge of a pool of water. There is a pretty good thread on what I am trying to do [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11585) but the solution isn't exactly what I am looking for. Since I will be calling ImageMagick from a C#.Net application I want to use one call without any temp files and return the image through stdout. So far I have this...

```
convert OriginalImage.png  ( OriginalImage.png -flip -blur 3x5 \
    -crop 100%%x30%%+0+0 -negate -evaluate multiply 0.3 \
    -negate  ( -size 585x128 gradient: ) +matte -compose copy_opacity -composite )
    -append NewImage.png
```

This works ok but doesn't give me the exact fade I am looking for. Instead of a nice solid fade from top to bottom it is giving me a fade from top left to bottom right. I added the (-negate -evaluate multiply 0.3 -negate) section in to lighten it up a bit more since I wasn't getting the fade I wanted. I also don't want to have to hard code in the size of the image when creating the gradient ( -size 585x128 gradient: ) I'm also going to want to keep the original image's transparency if possible.

To go to stdout I plan on replacing "NewImage.png" with "-"

Comment: I can answer this when I get home this evening.  Commenting so that I can find the question again on my user page.

Comment: I didn't put this in an answer because it doesn't directly address the constraints you expressed, but I think it's useful info (especially in a *nix oriented context): http://blogs.sun.com/constantin/entry/presenting_images_and_screenshots_the

Comment: Just for reference, here is a PHP script that utilizes the GD library to do what I believe you want: http://reflection.corephp.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling it from C#, perhaps you could get retrieve the image dimensions in C#.
Then call the ImageMagick command with

```
command = String.Format("convert bar %1x%2",img.Width,img.Height)
```

Comment: I'd rather not have to make a separate call to get the image size. Since ImageMagick will have the image loaded, I was hoping to be able to reuse the size information.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the existing image as an input, and create the gradient yourself using -fx instead of using the gradient pseudo-format.

Answer (score -1):

May be this can help:
[Reflection under an image](http://www.alleluia.ch/systeme-dexploitation/commande/107-reflexion-sous-une-image)

```
#!/bin/sh

gamma=$1
source=$2
destination=$3
size=`identify -format "%wx%h" $source`

convert $source \
  \( -size $size xc:none \
  \( \( -flip $source -crop $size+0+0 \) \
  -size $size gradient: -gamma $gamma \
  -compose copy_opacity -composite \) \
  -compose blend -composite \) \
  -append $destination
```