# How to create a reflection Effect using ImageMagick?

Tags: unix, imagemagick

What would be the command to create a reflection effect using ImageMagick which fades out as a gradient. Like shown in http://reflection.corephp.co.uk/gfx/shot.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling for "Imagemagick reflection effect" turns up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198928/imagemagick-reflection). 
If that doesn't help you completely, maybe the [ImageMagick Examples Gallery](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/) contains something to work with.

Edit: The Gallery indeed has [reflection examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/advanced/#reflections).

Comment: I checked it out. It doesn't have any convincing solution.